# Exact type of motor

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

What is the exact type of motor in below picture, especially the right one?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know they are brushless as I've added tag to this . but what kind of ? In right motor What are those notch at top of it's stator winding for ? is the right motor kind of stepper motor ?

Comment: was there a name plate on the side of the motor you can show us?

Comment: No fundamental difference.  Count windings (multiple of 3).  Count magnets (multiple of 2).

Comment: but the right one seems to be difference . In right motor What are those notch at top of it's stator winding for ? is the right motor kind of stepper motor ?

Comment: You should add your stepper motor comments to your question.  Count windings and magnets. A BLDC is a form of stepper motor in that the cycles of 3 phases advances it forward a step, but it is NOT a stepper motor.  Odds are they came out of washing machines.

Answer (score 0):

These appear to be outer-rotor, brushless stepper motors. In synchronous motors, the stator pole count matches the rotor pole count. That does not appear to be the case with these motors. If the rotor has permanent magnets, they are permanent-magnet motors, otherwise they are reluctance motors.

To fully describe the type of motor, the stator connection and energization scheme would need to be determined. The stator could have two, three or more phases. A pole winding can consist of two parts that can be alternatively energized to reverse the polarity rather than reversing the current in a single winding.

One of the two motors pictured in the question has the stator pole faces divided to provide a higher reluctance area in the center of the pole. The size of the lower-reluctance areas seems to match the size of the rotor pole faces. This would seem to provide more pole alignment alternatives with fewer wound stator poles. Several patents for such configurations suggest that there are several design strategies involved.

Both motors are permanent-magnet stepper motors. They are brushless, but most, if not all, stepper motors are brushless. Often, only the major design features are mentioned when classifying "types" of motors.

Comment: Yes they are outer-rotor . And their rotor has permanent magnet on them . but In right motor What are those notch at top of it's stator winding for ? is the right motor kind of stepper motor ?

Comment: I added a "divided-pole" paragraph and then revised it with a site shutdown intervening.